# Dell Optiplex 980 failure

Tags: windows-10, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell Optiplex 980 that was running for years with no problem. Now it crashed, it won't start and the diagnostic digits 1 and 3 are flashing on the front panel. Is there something I can do? Can I at least save the data on the HDD?

When I google about the diagnostic codes for digits 1 and 3 is says either RAM or motherboard failure. Is it possible to know what to do?

Comment: You can put the HDD in another PC, either as second drive, or using an inexpensive external enclosure (some are less than US$10) to try to salvage data.

Comment: After see this exact problem hundreds of times on multiple Dell's I will tell you that the simplest thing you can do to solve the problem (sometimes permanently and other times temporarily) is to place the RAM in different slots. It worked 100% of the time for me.

Comment: @JerryHundric I tried it and it didn't work. I also tried using only one slot, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if diagnostic lights 1 and 3 are flashing there are some things to consider.

Is your power button flashing?

If so, a possible system board, power supply, or peripheral failure has occurred.

Try these:

-Power off computer, leaving the computer plugged in. Press and hold the power supply test button on the rear of the power supply unit. If the LED next to the switch illuminates, the problem may be with your system board.

-If the LED next to the switch does not illuminate, disconnect all internal and external peripherals, and press and hold the power supply test button.If it illuminates, there could be a problem with a peripheral.

-If the LED still does not illuminate, remove the PSU connections from the system board, then press and hold the power supply button. If it illuminates, there could be a problem with the system board.

-If the LED still does not illuminate, the problem is probably with the power supply.

Is the powerbutton solid or otherwise not flashing?

If so, memory modules are detected, but a memory configuration or compatibility error has occurred.

Try these:

-Ensure that no special requirements for memory module/connector placement exist.

-Ensure that the memory you are using is supported by your computer.

-Possibly bad memory.

Comment: The power button is _not_ flashing.

Comment: Then from what you are saying, and my experience with them it sounds like you've either got a bad connection with your RAM. Or the RAM itself is potentially bad. As Jerry said up above, try moving them around and see if that works. Otherwise you can try new memory.